# Update datagrid without freezing the UI

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I was wondering if there is a way to update the datagrid without freezing the UI.

I have binded a datagrid to a list, I constantly keep adding records to the list and I want to update the datagrid at the same time. The problem is that to do that I need to refresh the source everytime.

My question is:
Is there anyway to update the datagrid directly and getting those updates to show without freezing the UI?

Example: Let's say I have a database from which I create a datagrid just for viewing the data (no editing the datagrid directly). I have made it possible to add a record by filling a form (productId,ProductName,Category,quantity...) and submiting when the button gets clicked I need the data to be added or a certain item to be updated in the datagrid without freezing the UI and finally update the database (which can be done later not necessarily everytime).

So let me rephrase my question what is the best way to do this.

Thanks,

Comment: If you're constantly adding items you may wanna take a look at `BackgroundWorker` class.

Comment: Bind the grid to an ObservableCollection and also perform your heavy actions on another thread.

Comment: provide a [mcve] that represents your current situation and the desired behavior

Comment: @Nkosi I updated my question. Cant be explained with code

Comment: @Const what is the current written code for this scenario? What have you tried so far. Cannot provide much help other than what I already suggested without seeing what you have already attempted.

Answer (score 0):

Following example run background service every 10 seconds to update GUI. You can modify it as you wish. By running your thread as async task your GUI never get hang.

```
public frm_testform()
{

    InitializeComponent();

    dispatcherTimer_Tick().DoNotAwait();

}

private async Task dispatcherTimer_Tick()
{
    DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs = null;
    EventHandler tickHandler = (s, e) => tcs.TrySetResult(true);

    timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
    timer.Tick += tickHandler;
    timer.Start();

    while (true)
    {
        tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
       // Run your background service and UI update here
        await tcs.Task;
    }

}
```

Sincerely,

Thiyagu Rajendran

**Please mark the replies as answers if they help and unmark if they don't.

Answer (score -1):

If I understood well You may want to use BindingList<> instead of List<>

Comment: That may be so for a winforms application but the OP is tagged with WPF.

Comment: sure. I've just noticed WPF tag